# Glitch when I enter texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

When im in layout window, in Eevee, everything is fine but when I change to texture paint mode, i have a glitch on my object as you can see. Looks like a grey stain. I didnt paint over it , i didnt even add a material to it and it giving me this problem. I checked to see if faces were flipped but everything is ok in terms of geometry. What could be the problem? Other objects are ok its just this one.

[image]

Comment: Possibly a shadow? Do you have a lamp close to the object on both sides?

Comment: It was a shadow from sun light, fixed it